# Java tiled paint

Tags: java, graphics

I'm writing a game, and I want an area of the screen to have a tiled paint drawn on it. Using a [TexturePaint](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html) java supports texturing a Shape with a tiled texture, this is really simple and performs pretty well. However, I want my tiled texture to be rotated before drawing it as a fill to the shape - this is theoretically possible by subclassing TexturePaint and applying a transform, However, this performs really badly.

Does java in some way support doing this? If not, is there any reasn that subclassing texturePaint might perform really badly?

Comment: What platform are you developing for?  If it's one that supports OpenGL (or any variant of it) I would recommend using that.  The Java2D API is not designed for games and this will probably not be the only performance problem you encounter.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a university game development project, which means that we simply don't have time to learn any new APIs, and of course the only API the entire team knows is the java2D one. :(

Comment: How does your current implementation look like?

Comment: We ended up hand tiling the texture tiles to make one really massive tile and then drawing that rotated. Reducing the number of tiles vastly improves the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best off just simply rotating the BufferedImage before throwing it at TexturePaint.

```
AffineTransform texture = new AffineTransform();
texture.rotate(radians, bufferedImage.getWidth()/2, bufferedImage.getHeight()/2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(texture, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```

You should be able to subclass TexturePaint without recieving a preformance drop, I can only assume that your rotation code is causing the drop.

I hope this helps.